# HTTPS when SSL folder is present in root?

Tags: ssl, nginx, https, subdomain

I want to force HTTPS for certain subdomains in nginx. I also do not want to edit the .conf file when i create a new subdomain that needs HTTPS. Is it possible to force HTTPS if an SSL folder is present in the root or something equivalent to it? So all i have to do to enable HTTPS on a new subdomain is add a new folder or something like that?

Here is my nginx.conf file:

```
    #HTTP DOMAIN.COM
    server {
       listen               80;
       server_name          *.domain.com;
       root                 /var/www/$http_host;


            location /ssl {
                    rewrite ^ https://$http_host/$1 redirect;
            }
```

edit:
I've been messing around a bit with symlinks but no luck yet. This is the new configuration I made:

```
server {
    listen              80;
    server_name         *.domain.com;
    root                /var/www/$http_host;

        location /var/www/ssl/$http_host {
                 rewrite  https://$http_host/$1 redirect;
        }

    include             error_page;
    include             location_php;
}
```

Am I coming close to my answer?

edit:
What I basically want is to be able to use ssl without having to change my .conf file.
All I need to do to enable HTTPS is change something somewhere around the docroot.

Comment: can you provide sample URL's of what to redirect and what not to redirect?

Comment: well i want sub2.domain.com to be https and when i have an ssl folder there i want to be able to just go to http://sub2.domain.com and that it automatically sees that there is an ssl folder in the docroot so it will be redirected to https://sub2.domain.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working! this is the config file:

```
server {
    listen          80;
    server_name     *.domain.com;
    root            /var/www/$host;

    if (-e /var/www/config/ssl/$host) {
            rewrite ^ https://$host$request_uri? permanent;
    }

    include         error_pages;
    include         php_config;
}
```

I still had to use an if statement but that's alright because it works now.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can enable SSL based merely on the existence of a directory. But you can extend the configuration using file globbing:

```
include vhosts/*.conf
include vhosts/ssl/*.conf
```

Just drop a minimal file in the directory.

(note that you still need to set up certificates, most likely on a per vhost basis - and these should not be incide the document root).

Comment: I've been searching around and found a tutorial of some kind (here is the link http://publications.jbfavre.org/web/nginx-vhosts-automatiques-avec-SSL-et-authentification.en) about dynamic SSL. It comes pretty close to what I want but they use if in the tutorial. Is there a way to avoid using IF and still achieve the same? (I'm not used to working with nginx yet)